# MXNET softmax output: label shape confusion

Tags: r, mxnet, softmax

I have not got a clear idea about how labels for the softmax classifier should be shaped.

What I could understand from my experiments is that a scalar laber indicating the index of class probability output is one option, while another is a 2D label where the rows are class probabilities, or one-hot encoded variable, like c(1, 0, 0).

What puzzles me though is that:

- I can use sclalar label values that go beyong indexing, like 4 in my
  example below -- without warning or error. Why is that?
- When my label is a negative scalar or an array with a negative value,
  the model converges to uniform probablity distribution over classes.
  For example, is this expected that `actor_train.y = matrix(c(0, -1,v0), ncol = 1)` results in equal probabilities in the softmax output?
- I try to use softmax MXNET classifier to produce the policy gradient
  reifnrocement learning, and my negative rewards lead to the issue
  above: uniform probability. Is that expected?

  require(mxnet)

  actor_initializer <- mx.init.Xavier(rnd_type = "gaussian", 
                                factor_type = "avg", 
                                magnitude = 0.0001)

  actor_nn_data <- mx.symbol.Variable('data') actor_nn_label <- mx.symbol.Variable('label')

  device.cpu <- mx.cpu()

  ### NN architecture

  actor_fc3 <- mx.symbol.FullyConnected(
       data = actor_nn_data
       , num_hidden = 3 )

  actor_output <- mx.symbol.SoftmaxOutput(
       data = actor_fc3
       , label = actor_nn_label
       , name = 'actor' )

  crossentfunc <- function(label, pred)
       {
       - sum(label * log(pred)) }

  actor_loss <- mx.metric.custom(
            feval = crossentfunc
            , name = "log-loss"
       )

  ## initialize NN

  actor_train.x <- matrix(rnorm(11), nrow = 1)

  actor_train.y = 0 #1 #2 #3 #-3 # matrix(c(0, 0, -1), ncol = 1)

  rm(actor_model)

  actor_model <- mx.model.FeedForward.create(
       symbol = actor_output,
       X = actor_train.x,
       y = actor_train.y,
       ctx = device.cpu,
       num.round = 100,
       array.batch.size = 1,
       optimizer = 'adam',
       eval.metric = actor_loss,
       clip_gradient = 1,
       wd = 0.01,
       initializer = actor_initializer,
       array.layout = "rowmajor" )

  predict(actor_model, actor_train.x, array.layout = "rowmajor")

Answer (score 0):

It is quite strange to me, but I found a solution.

I changed optimizer from `optimizer = 'adam'` to `optimizer = 'rmsprop'`, and the NN started to converge as expected in case of negative targets. I made simulations in R using a simple NN and `optim` function to get the same result.

Looks like `adam` or `SGD` may be buggy or whatever in case of multinomial classification... I also used to get stuck at the fact those optimizers did not converge to a perfect solution on just 1 example, while `rmsprop` does! Be aware!